# Mover ratón a una zona especifica en C#

Tags: c#, cursor, mouse

Quisiera mover el ratón a una ubicación especifica, he leído sobre la clase [Cursor](https://docs.microsoft.com/es-es/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.cursor?view=netframework-4.8) y soy consciente de que puedo moverlo dándole coordenadas, el problema está en que, hasta dónde he leido las coordenadas varían en función del número de pixeles que tenga que desplazarse.

Es decir, si yo muevo el cursor 50 pixeles a la derecha, en mi ordenador, en otro con una pantalla más grande se desplazará menos.

Me gustaría saber si hay alguna forma de moverlo porcentualmente, teniendo en cuenta el porcentaje total de la pantalla. He hecho esta imagen para que se vea más gráficamente lo que me gustaría.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Teniendo en cuenta que, el 100% del height and weight será el mismo en una pantalla de 10 pulgadas, como de 40, ¿cómo podría desplazar el ratón basandome en ese porcentaje?

Gracias de antemano.

```
System.Windows.Forms.Cursor.Position = new Point (
   SystemInformation.VirtualScreen.Width  * 8 / 100, 
   SystemInformation.VirtualScreen.Height * 19 / 100
);
```

Comment: Agrega el codigo que has intentado hasta el momento y que tipo de aplicacion estas implementando winform, wpf,...?

Comment: Winform, y hasta hora no he intentado nada puesto que las coordenadas no son las mismas para cada diferente pantalla @MiguelZarate

Comment: Pero puedes tener las coordenadas dependiendo del ancho y alto de pantalla, cuando esta completa y despues cuando la reduces, intenta algo agrega tu codigo, para poder ayudarte

Comment: Con Screen.PrimaryScreen.Bounds.Width & Screen.PrimaryScreen.Bounds.Height  obtienes el tamaño actual de tu ventana solo agregas porcentajes para ubicarlos por alto y ancho a la cuarta parte por .25  osea 25%

Comment: Hola de nuevo!, efectivamente hice lo que me dijiste, saqué el tamaño total y a partir de ahí hice una regla de tres con el porcentaje que necesitaba, me vas a matar pero... ¿Cómo demonios se hace para clickear? Edito el código arriba por si fuese útil

Answer (score 3):

Puedes hacer una simulacion para click :

```
    [System.Runtime.InteropServices.DllImport("user32.dll")]
    public static extern void mouse_event(int dwFlags, int dx, int dy, int cButtons, int dwExtraInfo);

    public const int MOUSEEVENTF_LEFTDOWN = 0x02;
    public const int MOUSEEVENTF_LEFTUP = 0x04;

    //Esto simula un click con el botón izquierdo del ratón
    public static void LeftMouseClick(int xpos, int ypos)
    {

        mouse_event(MOUSEEVENTF_LEFTDOWN, xpos, ypos, 0, 0);
        mouse_event(MOUSEEVENTF_LEFTUP, xpos, ypos, 0, 0);
    }

//ahora despues de que ubiques tu raton
//primero no declares tu llamado con la posicion directa declaras como variables
var pointX=  SystemInformation.VirtualScreen.Width  * 8 / 100, 
var pointY=   SystemInformation.VirtualScreen.Height * 19 / 100

System.Windows.Forms.Cursor.Position = new Point (
   pointX, 
   pointY
);

LeftMouseClick(pointX,pointY);//simula el click
```

Comment: Funciona perfectamente, muchísimas gracias! Una última pregunta sino es mucho molestar, por qué los métodos Hide and Show no funcionan correctamente?
Ejemplo: System.Windows.Forms.Cursor.Hide(); 
Pero en ningún momento el ratón es ocultado

Comment: He estado probando en otros ordenadores con distinta resolución y el ratón no se queda exactamente en la posición que debería.

Comment: El mouse no se debe ocultar, podrias enviarlo a una posicion inicial o moverlo a coordenadas negativas para ponerla fuera de vision, Ahora dices que tu posicion no es exacta pero para que usas el click es decir lo posicionas en un objeto y simulas el click, en ese caso debes obtener la posicion de dicho objeto mover el mouse a esa posicion

Comment: Si muevo el mouse fuera de la pantalla entonces después no podré hacer click, mi idea es poder hacer click en (x,y) coordenadas sin que se vea

Comment: En caso que no quieras que el mouse de vea en el boton no lo cambies de posicion siplemente llama a LeftMouseClick(int xpos, int ypos) con las coordenadas que tu indiques.

Comment: Cuándo me comentaste que simulaba el click se me vino a la mente esa posibilidad, e intenté LeftMouseClick(SystemInformation.VirtualScreen.Width * 8 / 100, SystemInformation.VirtualScreen.Height * 10 / 100); lo acabo de volver a intentar, pero en ningún momento hace click en esa posición (aún si el ratón no se desplaza evidentemente porque no se cambia la posición de éste, no hace click en ningún momento) ¿Es posible que se deba a que la coordenada está fuera del windows form?

Comment: Bueno puedes mover el raton hacer click y regresarlo a su posicion original, no se si sea visible esto.